Issue solving a recurrence relation
I´m trying to solve the following recurrence relation in Mathematica:
cl[n_, k_] := (k (1 - k + n) Binomial[n, k])/n
RSolve[{b[n, k] == 
   Sum[b[n - 1, k - k1] + 
     cl[2 n - 1, k1] Binomial[(n - 2)^2, k - k1], {k1, 0, 2 n - 1}], 
  b[n, 1] == n^2, b[0, k] == 0, b[n, n^2 + 1] == 0}, b[n, k], {n, k}]

However, it doesn´t return any result, instead, it throws the RSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently. error. How can I modify this RSolve[] call so that it provides a closed form for b[n,k]?

The error message stems from the term b[n, n + 1] == 0.  Eliminate it, and RSolve produces no error messages but also no solution.  I do not believe that RSolve can solve this problem.  In fact, the problem may not be well posed.  Over what range of {n, k} are you expecting an answer?  Also, why do you expect a closed-form solution?

@bbgodfrey $b(n,k)$ should be valid when $n>0$ and $0< k \leq n^2$. If $k=0$ or $n<1$ or $k>n^2$ it should return 0.

Sum in your code can include terms with negative values of k - k1.  Check the limits.  However, even after you correct the limits of the sum, 'RSolve` may not be able to solve the problem.
